# display records in table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am having some trouble with my first PHP project, I am trying to get the data from MySQL database (Has 3 records) and display it in tables. Problem is it only seem to display records 2 and 3, it skips the 1st record. Please see my code and display below.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM unitstats");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<table border='1' style='color:white'>
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the first `while` doing?

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` I don't think you know what this does T.T

Comment: why all the answers are being downvoted?

Comment: I haven't voted anything yet :s But yeah I don't really know what that does yet, I'm just starting to learn PVP and I'm originally a VB Programmer. I thought that fetch code is just some required code

Comment: Oh shoot! I have two while statements lol, the first one for the headers won't be needing that, sorry guys, my level is still stupid (Lv.10 swordsman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using two while loop which is unnecessary use following code

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

      echo "</table>";


echo "<table border='1' style='color:white'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM unitstats");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {


echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: is this answer something different that others gave here?why this is upvoted and else all others are downvoted?

Comment: @user2936213 ask them who upvote this answer. any way have you not seen that this answer is also accepted by question owner?

Comment: its not only for u satish, but there is someone who is doing this stuff.he is just trying to make all of us reputation down without any reason.

Comment: i didn't know about this. overall self satisfaction is more important rather than the upvote/downvote. feel free from this.

Comment: yeah ur right :) but because this our account may get blocked na thats why.anyways it was just a curiosity to know this :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

echo "<table border='1' style='color:white'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM unitstats");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";
```

Basically you didn't need the initial loop, this would have mainly caused an issue because you would have been redeclaring `$row` with the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your outer while loop and just use this:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM unitstats");


echo "<table border='1' style='color:white'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```